# Multi-page Applications with Meteor/React

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, routes, flow-router

I am new to Meteor/React and am trying to figure out how to create a multi-page application. I'm getting really confused about how to actually get routing to work. I want to have multiple html files that, depending on what happens on one, will cause another one to be rendered. For example,

I'm on main.html and I click a button -> and it should then cause secondary.html to render on the screen. I hit another button on secondary.html -> and it directs me to tertiary.html.

However, whenever I launch an application, all my html files just get rendered all at once (something that Meteor just does automatically I guess). I've been trying to work with FlowRouter. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What have you done with the FlowRouter ? the tutorial is quite straight forward and will not lead to the situation that you are having now. Each route will have a particular rendered template

Comment: One thing I'm really confused about is that you use ReactLayout.render(Layout) to render a react component, but it always just renders on the page I'm currently on. Say I have index.html and about.html and I want it to render onto a second page after a click, how do I do that? It always just ends up being rendered at the bottom of the first page.

Comment: do you accidentally include the index component back to the about component ? sharing some codes here could help

Comment: Ah Sorry! I got some of it working, now my problem is trying to make my React components render in the place I want it to.

Comment: So let's say: that I have a <div id="place"></div> and I want React.Layout.render(Layout) the layout component to the div, how can I do that? I tried doing ReactLayout.render(Layout, document.getElementbyId('place')) but it doesn't work

Comment: Overall, how can you control where on the page to render your React components through the router?

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting confortable with iron:router package, you can see the documentation here : https://atmospherejs.com/iron/router

Have a look on what options you can add to this by visiting the documentation...

But still, this is how you implement it the easiest way :

```
Router.route("/myCustomRoute",function(){
this.render("/myCustomTemplate")
}
```

By doing this, you will allow your application to have multiples routes :) 
However, FlowRouter is a very good option (maybe better) but it will be the same "logic of code" behind :)

Hope it will help !